# rspec expectations on block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the below code under test:

```
class MethodCache
    @@methods=Hash.new

    def self.add_method(name, &block)
        @@methods[name]=block
    end

    def self.get_method(name)
        @@methods[name]
    end
end
```

Now my spec looks like this:

```
describe MethodCache do
    subject {MethodCache}
    foo_block = ->{ puts "foo"}
    it ".get_method" do
        subject.add_method "foo", &foo_block
        # does not work
        # expect(subject.get_method("foo").to be &foo_block 

        # should syntax works
        subject.get_method("foo").should be foo_block

    end
end
```

I am trying to stay away from `should` syntax and use the `expect` syntax of RSpec. However it does not work in this case.

`expect(subject.get_method("foo").to be &foo_block` fails saying `wrong number of arguments`. I guess this is because the expectation block is treated as a block argument.

`expect(subject.get_method("foo").to be foo_block` (without the '&') does not work either. It says, the matcher expects a value and not argument.

What am I missing here?